# How can my DbContext contain the same entity twice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I had to do some gymnastics to update an entity that contained a reference to another entity and I do not understand why, because in my side test project it works without.

The problem seems to be that the DbContext contains multiple entities with the same primary key but with other property changed.

So, I have to do something like the code below to set the reference correctly.

If I do not do this, I create a new "Tax" entity in the database, which is not what I want but a reference to the existing one.

```
 if (!Database.Set<Tax>().Local.Any(e => e.ID == invoiceDetail.Tax.ID))
    Database.Taxes.Attach(invoiceDetail.Tax);
 else
    invoiceDetail.Tax = Database.Set<Tax>().Local.Single(e => e.ID == invoiceDetail.Tax.ID);
```

Why do I have to check manually the Local object to make it works? Why does the DbContext contain more than 1 instance of an Entity which has the primary key identical? I am using EF4.3 in Code First (Poco).

Comment: EF context never contains two instances of the entity with the same key. Explain what you are trying to do - I guess it is very common problem with detached entities.

Comment: MVC receive the data from the Request. I know that it loads Tax entity with id #1 from the database because I load the existing InvoiceDetail from the database to update the scalar but the problem is that I do not attach, it adds a new Tax which is not what I want. If I attach a new instance of Tax{ID=1} it works but only once. If I have multiple Tax in my InvoiceDetail it crash saying that only once occurence  need to be inside the Tax. You can see the code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141597/how-to-insert-a-new-entity-that-contain-references-to-existing-entity-without-du

Comment: In fact, I would prefer not having to do the ELSE assignation but if I do not I have a new Tax created. The ID is 100% existing in the database (the only difference is that I have not all others property filled up since it came from MVC Request.