# DatabaseContext contain a DbSet with duplicate entity, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

When saving the InvoiceDetail with Entity Framework we check if the Tax information has been removed or not, if we see that we still have Tax, we check if we already have the Tax inside the DbSet of Tax cause we just want the reference to this object to our InvoiceDetail. To do that we simply check the Local property and get the Tax from the Local.

```
if (formInvoiceDetail.Tax != null) {
    if (formInvoiceDetail.Tax.ID == 0) {
        databaseInvoiceDetail.Tax = null;
    }
    else {
        if (!Database.Set<Tax>().Local.Any(e => e.ID == formInvoiceDetail.Tax.ID)){
            Database.Taxes.Attach(formInvoiceDetail.Tax);
        }
        databaseInvoiceDetail.Tax = Database.Set<Tax>().Local.Single(e => e.ID == formInvoiceDetail.Tax.ID);
    }                
}
```

The problem is that we have scenarios where the Single crash because the ID is duplicated in the DbSet of Tax.

This occur when previous operation set additional existing Tax information (for example a first load will load InvoiceDetail with the Tax object (just its ID) and later on, will change the invoiceDetail.Tax = fullLoadedTax.

How do we proceed if we want not to have duplicated data in the DbSet and always "most accurate" one?

Comment: "most accurate one" means to open the context just before using it or refresh your local objects. Single() causes an exception if there is no e.ID == Tax.ID [compared to SingleOrDefault()], and mostlikely not cos of duplicates..?

Comment: The problem is that the ID found 2 entry. One with the Tax object with only the id and name. The other one with full information (like numbers).

Comment: Btw: Are there any special collections/indexers definied? If ID is a working entity key, EF wont allow you to attach it twice (usually). Maybe other codes add this entity to the server using another context? You should definitely provide more details/codes..

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179754

Answer (score 1):

Is ID is a primary key in the database that Entity is mapping, because if so the snippet of code where you get

```
   invoiceDetail.Tax = fullLoadedTax
```

is violating your database's constraints.  It strikes me that your problem is with this line of code, not anything you've shown in your question, per se.  If you were properly qualifying and updating your local database it wouldn't have its constraints violated and you wouldn't have this problem.  When you're messing around with fullLoadedTax, try to use [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466205.aspx):

```
 Database.Taxes.ApplyCurrentValues(formInvoiceDetail.Tax);
```

This *should* update things to give you a consistent, up-to-date setup, but truthfully if ID was properly set up as a primary key in the first place then attempting to Attach() a second record with an identical key would blow up in your face anyway, so you might also have to take another look at how you're handling your DbContext.

Comment: The ID is indeed the primary key. I do not have problem with database constraints, the problem remain that when I am setting the Tax to the invoiceDetail that this one can't because the .Single() return more than once instance of the tax. I am not updating the information of the tax but just the reference of between invoicedetail and tax. ApplyCurrentvalues won't work because it will apply only scalar property and the Tax is not.

Comment: The local database in Entity is supposed to generally mirror the database it's mapped to.  If you're returning more than one instance in .Local, you would attempt to map two rows when you go back to the database. This is an error if it's a primary key.  I was under the impression that ApplyCurrentValues would apply scalar sub-values if you passed it an object but I guess I'm off base if you tried that.  The thing that immediately comes to mind is Detatching the row based on ID and then reattaching it.  I would try that, see if it works, and probably look for something more graceful if it does.

Comment: You are right, that may give an error while going to the database, still, I do not understand why the .Local doesn't replace the first entity with the second one when this one add it to the .Local. Why adding 2 entities with the same ID in the .Local if it's something forbidden...

Comment: For whatever unholy reason your .Local object isn't picking up the uniqueness requirements from retrieving the database.  It might be that your POCOs are messed up somehow, I can really only speculate without knowing what you're looking at.